# Android MenuItem Bottom Padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

I was curious, since I couldn't really find anything on this, if there was a way to do what happens, when you say have tabs with android, for a normal action button. Onclick on the button, I was curious if there was a way to highlight the bottom of it like the below image. Please give me your thoughts, right now, I can switch the image fine, but I am really looking for just an indication while they are inside that buttons fragment to see as is shown below where movies has the highlighted bar under it. So for my menuitem when they click it until they go back, to normalize it, I was curious if I could get this functionality somehow. [image]

Comment: actually they are tab on landscape modes

Comment: Either way, that is the functionality I am looking for with how it looks.